# Конвертер DateTime из dataGridView в MsSql

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server, datagridview

Доброе утро, у меня из бд отображается datagridView, 
 проблема в том что последний столбец является типом datetime
 и обратно  из грида в бд он не парсится
кидает exception

> Необработанное исключение типа "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException" в
>   System.Data.dll
>
> Дополнительные сведения: Conversion failed when converting date and/or
>   time from character string.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionStr))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                   foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
                    {
                        string sqlExpression = string.Format(
      "Insert into XmlTable (FileVersion, FileName, DateChanged) values ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}')",
               row.Cells[0], row.Cells[1], row.Cells[2];

                        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlExpression, connection);
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
```

в гриде это поле выглядит так 21.12.16
 т е через точку
пробывал добавить 
.ToString().Replace('.','-')); 
не помогло. 
Ячейка с datetime находится в позиции {2} проверял
Эта кнопка последняя все работает сегодня сдаю

Comment: а какой формат дат в БД известно ?

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych Размумеется все известно в бд формат DateTime, программа загружает данные из .xml файла в бд, потом данные редактируются в гриде и сохраняются обратно в бд.

Comment: модель: .xml -> БД -> DataGridView-> БД

Answer (score 0):

Для начала общий ответ: Почитайте про форматы даты и времени в SQL Server в этой статье, вам станет понятно, откуда растут ноги у вашей проблемы:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql

Теперь более конкретный ответ:

Если вы хотите импортировать значения именно так, то генерируйте вместо "'{2}'" такую строчку: "convert(date, '''{2}''', 4)" - так вы явно укажете СУБД, в каком формате ваша дата и как ее надо распознавать.

Альтернатива вашему решению - передача полного XML внутрь запроса и парсинг его уже методами T-SQL - этот диалект языка достаточно давно умеет парсить XML.

Answer (score 0):

В **datagridView** поменяйте формат даты на `месяц/день/год"`,потом при чтении этого поля можете напиать вот так!

```
string date = "12.28.16";
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(str);
```

В вашем же сличайи `Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells[2])`

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему следующим кодом

```
var dt = Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells[2].Value);

     var str = string.Format("DATETIMEFROMPARTS( {0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6} )",
   dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day, dt.Hour, dt.Minute, dt.Second, dt.Millisecond);
```

дальше str вставляю в sql команду в колонке dateTime